Does conservative orthography promote "phonetic denial"?
Are there speech-communities that assert that the gemination (still) present in their orthography (still) exists in their pronunciation, but audio analysis does not support this assertion?
I guess this is part of a broader question of whether conservative orthography impairs phonetic awareness.
I am particularly interested in the case of pointed Biblical Hebrew. In that case no speech-community asserts that they have preserved all distinctions present in the orthography. But I wonder whether they assert that they have preserved some distinctions that in fact they have lost.
How does one even ask such a question without seeming disrespectful? I've probably failed, for which I apologize in advance. It seems to me both an important and a delicate question, to ask whether people are making the sound-distinctions they assert that they are making.

Are you asking specifically about people who have learned phonetics and the associated terminology? A lot of English-speakers still talk about "long vowels" when they mean "vowels that were long pre-GVS", since that's how the terminology is used in schools, but generally that's restricted to English-speakers who haven't taken introductory phonetics classes.

Thanks @Draconis for asking me to refine my question. I'm asking about people who may not have learned the technical vocabulary of phonetics, but still have some way of asserting a phonetic distinction. E.g. they may not use the word "gemination," but they assert that certain consonants are "longer" or "emphasized" or "bigger," etc. Or they might use some surprising term like a green consonant. As long as this is opposed to something like a red consonant, they are asserting a distinction.

it doesn't seem to directly address the question here, but there are plenty of Spanish-speakers who'll insist they distinguish  and , despite the fact these stopped being distinguished within the Vulgar Latin period

@Draconis English vowels are perhaps not the best example – they’re complicated by the fact that the (now tense) vowels that arose from pre-GVS long vowels are often longer in duration than their lax/pre-GVS short counterparts, especially in BrE. Not always (e.g., man and mane are roughly equal), but quite commonly (e.g., heed is noticeably longer than hid).

I can think of a phonetically innocent person (my mother) who insisted that there was an /r/ in words like "there" in our non-rhotic version of English. I suspect that her familiarity with Pitman Shorthand, which used the R-stroke for such words, played a part in this conviction. So I suppose that is a confirming anecdote for your suggestion.

@ColinFine This might not be due to orthography, as people may genuinely be perceiving an R there due to the linking R rule.

What is conservative orthography?

@Lambie one reflecting the phonology of an older stage of a language

One should perhaps distinguish between:

a false perception of a phonetic distinction in someone's own speech or in the language in general
the feeling that a distinction does exist in the "proper" pronunciation but that speakers "corrupt" this pronunciation by merging phonemes
lack of awareness of certain phonetic phenomena such as vowel reduction, voicing/devoicing and sandhi

Adding to Tristan's observation about the (lack of) distinction between 'v' and 'b' in Spanish, I think one example of a false perception is the lack of a phonetic distinction between the short stressed realizations of the graphemes 'ä' and 'e' in Standard German. See the discussion here. I myself had this experience of talking to educated native speakers who tried to convince me that there was or must have been a phonetic distinction.
In the case of Hebrew, since it has not been spoken as a first language up until end of 19th century, the distinction between the different phenomena above is particularly relevant. I'm not aware of examples of false perception of a phonetic distinction, but there have indeed been cases when a wide-spread pronunciation of Hebrew was reflected upon by the more perceptive observers from within the community who noticed that it started to diverge from how Hebrew "ought to be pronounced" - see examples in Dovid Katz'es "The phonology of Ashkenazic". It is not always clear whether in these cases the critic follows a tradition which genuinely survived the phonetic merger or whether he cautiously adjusts his own pronunciation (how successfully?) despite the merger he and everyone else already had.
An example of a lack of awareness (3.) might be final devoicing and vowel reduction among some Hebrew speakers of Russian background and lack of distinction between /v/ and /b/ among speakers of Spanish background.
See also a related phenomenon when graphics influences pronunciation.
